# Check whether user of non-facebook app likes/shares particular URL on FB 

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke, share, facebook-like

I'd like to know if there is a possibility to check (using Graph API or any other way) whether given user likes / shares a specific link. Probably I'll have this user's facebook ID or facebook login, but my site is non-Facebook application. Actually it's Dot Net Nuke portal (target: .NET with MS SQL Server) with part of it being avaliable as Facebook app, but certainly not greater part of it, so the solution should be out of Facebook Connect, although it's not a showstopper if it's necessary.

We'll be giving points to users who share/like most of links that we serve in our portal and such possibility would be a great help to make a ranking.

Another option we consider is making some kind of "wrapper" or proxy for FB like / share buttons which will at first save some data in our database (probably - this user clicked on like for this link) and then go on with standard FB like / share route. Did anybody of You tried such solution?

If You have any other suggestion on the subject, please, post them, we'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to know if a user has LIKED a site or not. You can get all user's likes with Graph API (you need `user_likes` permission). Take a look at the docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

I'm not sure if you can know if he has shared your site, but you could try by parsing his wall with the `read_stream` permission and then look for your site name/URL post by post.

Answer (score 0):

For just general liking of items on your site, you can use a [Facebook Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). However, you won't be able to associate (or really even access) user activity with users on your site without integrating Facebook Connect and creating a Facebook application for your site. At that point you can design with greater control all the possible user activity and interleave with your facebook calls other calls that affect users' accounts on your site.